# $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{x^2}{x^2+x})^x = 1 $ or $0$?

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+x}\right)^x$$

as $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^2+x} = 1$ but we all know that $\frac{x^2}{x^2+x} < 1$ and for $a<1$ lim $\lim_{x\to\infty} a^x = 0$

I don't know how to find the limit in this case

Comment: Neither. See mathlove's answer below for a serious hint

Comment: The $a$ you are getting here is not fixed but changes with $x$.

Answer (score 7):

Note that
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+x}\right)^x=\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}\right)^x=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac 1x\right)^x}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Mathlove privided an efficient way forward.  Here is a slightly different approach.  Take the logarithm of the function of interest.  Then, we have

$$\log\left(\frac{x^2}{x+x^2}\right)^x=x\log\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)=\frac{\log\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{\log x- \log (1+x)}{\frac{1}{x}}$$

Now, apply L'Hospital's Rule to find

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \log\left(\frac{x^2}{x+x^2}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x}- \frac{1}{1+x}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=-1$$

Since the exponential function is continuous, then we have

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{x^2}{x+x^2}\right)^x=e^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Cancel an $x$, for a start:
$$ \frac{x^2}{x^2+x} = \frac{x}{x+1}, $$
so we're looking at
$$(1+x)^{-x} = e^{-x(\log{(1+x)}-\log{x})}$$
Since the exponential is continuous, look at what happens to
$$ -x\log{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)} $$
as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Note that $\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+x} = \dfrac{x}{x+1}$